# Uncaught ReferenceError : unimplemented is not defined

Tags: javascript, svg, processing

I am running a sketch in Javascript mode in Processing and I am getting an error called Uncaught ReferenceError : unimplemented is not defined when I am running the following code:

```
PShape mirror;
void setup() {
  mirror = loadShape("mirror.svg");
}
void draw() {
  shape(mirror,0,0,400,80);
}
```

Can anyone please explain the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Uncaught ReferenceError : /*object/function*/ is not defined` appears when JavaScript does not recognize a certain object or function; or in your case, it does not recognize "unimplemented".

Since "unimplemented" is not in your code sample—and I have gotten your code to work in Processing 3.0.2 (the latest version) on my machine, then I can safely assume that a built-in function is not being loaded properly. There might be an error with your particular installation of Processing or JavaScript.

Although I do not fully understand the nature of this error, I suggest a fresh install of the latest version of Processing, which can be found here: https://processing.org/download/?processing

Lastly, this is likely not the cause of the error, but make sure that mirror.svg is in a folder called "data" within your sketch folder.